# React context, I get an error when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What I'm trying to do is to call my service on the main page and then assign context to the response and print it in another component. I can print but when I refresh the page I get an error.

**home.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { PolicyContext } from 'contexts/PolicyContext';
import { PolicyService } from 'services/PolicyService';
const Home = () => {

  const { policyData, setPolicyData } = useContext(PolicyContext);

  const activiesPolicyExampleReq = {
    nationalId: '59104492600',
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    PolicyService.getActivePolicies(activiesPolicyExampleReq).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        setPolicyData(response);
      }
    );
  }, []);
}
```

**PolicyContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

export const PolicyContext = createContext(undefined);

const PolicyContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [policyData, setPolicyData] = useState();
  console.log('PC');
  return (
    <PolicyContext.Provider
      value={useMemo(() => {
        return ({
          policyData,
          setPolicyData,
        });
      }, [{ policyData, setPolicyData }])}
    >
      {props.children}
    </PolicyContext.Provider >
  );
};

export default PolicyContextProvider;
```

**App.js**

```
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppRouter from 'routes/AppRouter';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
import Header from 'modules/Header';
import Login from 'pages/login/login';
import Onboarding from './pages/onboarding/onboarding';
import PolicyContextProvider from './contexts/PolicyContext';
import React from 'react';
import Theme from 'theme/Theme';
import { history } from './libs/History';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Theme>
      <CookiesProvider>
        <PolicyContextProvider>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Route exact path={['/onboarding']} component={Onboarding} />
            <Route exact path={['/login']} component={Login} />
            <Header />
            <AppRouter />
          </Router>
        </PolicyContextProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    </Theme>
  );
}
```

**the component i want to print**

```
  const { policyData, setPolicyData } = useContext(PolicyContext);
  console.log(policyData);

          <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
            <PolicyCarousel
              policyList={
                policyData.activePoliciesMap
                  ? policyData.activePoliciesMap[policiesMapType]
                  : null
              }
              policyType={0}
            />
          </TabPanel>
```

error in console:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'activePoliciesMap')

Comment: Here: `policyData.activePoliciesMap` `policyData` is undefined. So when you try to check for `activePolicyMap` it throws error. Make sure its initialised properly

Comment: Whenever you refresh a page, react states and contexts will be returned to it's initial state. You might need to store those variables in localStorage.